# How to get multiple rows data in two different column of same id in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have one table and data in it. Below is the table

```
+----+-------+------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| Id | p_name| grade| promoted| created_on  | review_by |
+----+-------+------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | Abc   | A    |   Yes   | 2023-Jun-14 |    AK     |
| 1  | Abc   | A    |   Yes   | 2023-Jun-17 |    RSK    |
| 1  | Abc   | B    |   Yes   | 2023-Jun-15 |    PS     |
| 1  | Abc   | B    |   Yes   | 2023-Jun-16 |    ZX     |
| 2  | Pqr   | A    |   Yes   | 2023-May-10 |    CB     |
| 2  | Pqr   | B-   |   Yes   | 2023-May-05 |    MN     |
| 2  | Pqr   | B    |   Yes   | 2023-May-07 |    KL     |
+----+-------+------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

I need below result and it is based on conditions

```
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------------+
| Id | p_name| Date for AA  | review_by for AA  | Date for BB  | review_by for BB |
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------------+ 
| 1  |  Abc  | 2023-Jun-17  |    RSK            | 2023-Jun-16  |      ZX          | 
| 2  |  Pqr  | 2023-May-10  |    CB             | 2023-May-7   |      KL          | 
+----+-------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

conditions : -

1. When Grade in ( A,A-) and promoted = Yes  then
   select  Latest Date('created on' column) save value into "Date for AA" column
   and ('revew_by' column as per latest date) save value into "review_by for AA" column
2. When Grade in ( B,B-) and promoted = Yes  then
   select  Latest_Date('created_on' column) save value into "Date for BB" column
   and ('revew_by' column as per latest date) save value into "review_by for BB" column

This condition is for each id(1,2) and get single result for each id as  mention in
result table.

In details : - Latest Date When Grade  A/A-  is promoted to Yes in "Date for AA"
column and reviewby as per latest date of  "created_on" column and it should be group by id.
And Latest Date When Grade  B/B-  is promoted to Yes in "Date for BB"
column and reviewby as per latest date of  "created_on" column and it should be group by id

Comment: and how does your query look like now

Comment: There is an assumption in the above that the rows are in a certain order e.g. it is assumed that the first 2 rows lead to a combined value of "AA"  - but you CANNOT rely on the order of rows to be processed that way, they could be processed in any sequence. You HAVE TO specify a way to control how the rows are to be paired together - this probably requires a "order by". Perhaps there are more columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns the incorrect value for `review_by for BB` for `Id = 2`. This is because you are returning `MAX(review_by)` per group, not `review_by` for `MAX(created_on)` per group.

Assuming you are using MySQL >= 8.0, you can use ROW_NUMBER() in a CTE, and then your conditional aggregation to pivot the remaining rows:

```sql
WITH max_t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, LEFT(grade, 1) ORDER BY created_on DESC) AS rn
    FROM table_name
    WHERE promoted = 'Yes'
)
SELECT Id, p_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN grade IN('A', 'A-') THEN created_on END) AS 'Date for AA',
    MAX(CASE WHEN grade IN('A', 'A-') THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for AA', 
    MAX(CASE WHEN grade IN('B', 'B-') THEN created_on END) AS 'Date for BB',
    MAX(CASE WHEN grade IN('B', 'B-') THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for BB'
FROM max_t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY Id, p_name;
```

For older versions of MySQL, you can use an aggregate query to get the max dates as a derived table and then join back to the main table:

```sql
SELECT t.Id, t.p_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.grade IN('A', 'A-') THEN t.created_on END) AS 'Date for AA',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.grade IN('A', 'A-') THEN t.review_by END) AS 'review_by for AA', 
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.grade IN('B', 'B-') THEN t.created_on END) AS 'Date for BB',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.grade IN('B', 'B-') THEN t.review_by END) AS 'review_by for BB'
FROM table_name t
JOIN (
    SELECT Id, LEFT(grade, 1) AS grade2, MAX(created_on) max_created_on
    FROM table_name
    WHERE promoted = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY Id, grade2
) t_max
    ON t.Id = t_max.Id
    AND LEFT(t.grade, 1) = t_max.grade2
    AND t.created_on = t_max.max_created_on
GROUP BY t.Id, t.p_name;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rs3xe5cH).

Answer (score 0):

my old query is

```
SELECT  Id, p_name,
(CASE WHEN (grade = 'A' OR grade = 'A-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN Max(created_on) END) AS 'Date for AA',
(CASE WHEN (grade = 'A' OR grade = 'A-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for AA',
(CASE WHEN (grade = 'B' OR grade = 'B-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN Max(created_on) AS 'Date for BB',
(CASE WHEN (grade = 'B' OR grade = 'B-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for BB'
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Id, p_name;
```

After some little changes, i got my answer.Below is correct query

```
SELECT Id, p_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN (grade = 'A' OR grade = 'A-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN created_on END) AS 'Date for AA',
MAX(CASE WHEN (grade = 'A' OR grade = 'A-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for AA', 
MAX(CASE WHEN (grade = 'B' OR grade = 'B-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN created_on END) AS 'Date for BB',
MAX(CASE WHEN (grade = 'B' OR grade = 'B-') AND promoted = 'Yes' THEN review_by END) AS 'review_by for BB'
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Id, p_name
```